# Python wheel packages Linux vs windows

Tags: python, pip, package, python-wheel

Can one use the same python package (wheel file) for Linux , windows etc.? I am asking this as some packages include not only python files but EXEs as well, which I assume are python code turned into exe (at least with pip.exe and Django admin tool). Exe files are platform specific in the  same way there are separate python interpreters for windows and Linux so that arises a question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some wheel packages are cross-platform; some are platform-specific.

This information is included in the wheel's name. For [example](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/#files):

```
pytz-2018.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510kB)
```

That `py2.py3` means that it works in any Python implementation, both Python 2.x and 3.x, and that `none-any` means that it works on any platform.
[This one](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.14.3/#files) is more specific:

```
numpy-1.14.3-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
```

That `cp36-cp36m` means that it works only in CPython 3.6, and that `macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64` means that it's built for x86_64 macOS versions 10.9-10.10. (Roughly speaking, that's the minimum and recommended versions of macOS; most other platforms aren't quite as complicated.)

---

The most common reason for a package to be platform-specific is that it includes C API extension modules, as is the case with numpy. But there can be other reasons. For example, it may include a native executable to `subprocess`, or it may use `ctypes` to access system APIs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A Python [wheel](https://pythonwheels.com/) is a packaging format, NOT an execution format.  It's basically a .zip file.

Furthermore:

> https://packaging.python.org/discussions/wheel-vs-egg/
>
> ...when the distribution only contains Python files (i.e. no compiled
>   extensions), and is compatible with Python 2 and 3, it’s possible for
>   a wheel to be “universal”, similar to an sdist.

From the same link:

> A single wheel archive can indicate its compatibility with a number of
>   Python language versions and implementations, ABIs, and system
>   architectures.

In other words, the "wheel" format is designed to be as portable as possible ... and it also allows you to include platform-specific contents as required.